# selecting on different column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table with columns id, selector, name:

```
  1 |  ONE | A
  2 |  TWO | A
  3 |  ONE | C
  4 |  ONE | C
  5 |  ONE | E
  6 |  ONE | E
  7 |  TWO | E
  8 |  TWO | H
```

I need a query which returns me all different name values for which there is more than one row and these rows contain at least two different selector values.
For the example above I would expect A and E as result.
H is not expected because there is only one row.
C is not expected because all rows have the same selector.
I could use a group by and having clause on the selector column,
but then I can't select the name as result...

My try

```
select selector 
from mytable 
group by selector 
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: what did you try till now?

Comment: select selector from mytable
group by selector
having count(*) > 1

Comment: But I need the name instead of the selector value...

Comment: @Holger - You need to update the query in question not in comment

Comment: I asked for your code, just because you need to show that you made an effort to solve your problem when you ask a question on StackOverflow. You were on the right way, change selector for name in the SELECT and in the GROUP BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Group by` and `having` clause.

Instead of `*` in `count` aggregate use `Distinct column_name` in `count` aggregate to filter the group which is having more than one **distinct** values

```
select column3 from yourtable 
group by column3 
having count(distinct column2)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   select name
     from Table1
 group by name
   having count(distinct selector) > 1
```

You can see a demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/31d77/1)

Comment: then remove it :)

I fixed the query and the demo, the original one was running because the DB in SQLFiddler was SQLServer